# Configuration file for kernel in VM environment

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I downloaded a fresh kernel that I'm planning on using in a VM. In the instructions of the tutorial I'm using, I'm told

> You will also need to build a new instance of the kernel, and ensure
>   that it will boot in the VM. To do this, move to your source tree,
>   copy config-3.14.26-yocto-qemu to
>   $SRC_ROOT/.config (where $SRC_ROOT is the root of your linux tree),
>   and run `make -j4 all`.

I did that by

- `cd linux-yocto-3.14` to go to the root of the linux tree
- `mkdir .config` to make the configuration folder that didn't exist in this brand new kernel
- copying `config-3.14.26-yocto-qemu` from outside the kernel into `/.config`
- While at the root of the kernel, executing `make -j4 all`

My concern is that after this step, the guide says it'll take about 5-minutes or so to build and that I can simply just leave it to do its thing; I thought the point of the config file was to build the kernel for me. Instead, I get prompted with the typical kernel build setup screen where I have to go through every single option to build the kernel. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have done the `mkdir .config`; you should have just copied the existing config file to a *filename* called `.config` in the kernel source directory.

e.g.

```
cd linux-yocto-3.14
cp /path/to/config-3.14.26-yocto-qemu .config
make -j4 all
```

Comment: The reason why I was doing `mkdir .config` is because when I'd go inside the Yocto folder and `ls .config`, it would spit out `ls: cannot access .config: No such file or directory` so I didn't think the folder existed. I did as you wrote and it worked! Thanks :]